# How to launch an SP 2010 Dialog Window Maximized

Tags: sharepoint-2010, coding-style, modal-dialog

I have modified **EditForm.aspx** of a list in **SharePoint 2010**. I need to **launch the dialog window** (that's what EditForm.aspx seems to be launched as) **maximized**, but I haven't been able to find the correct setting to tweak.

A quick web search suggests to use the **showMaximized:true** style setting, but I am unable to find the element in EditForm.aspx to apply this attribute to.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove **ALL** dialogs from a list, go to:

list settings -> advanced -> dialog -> turn them off

But if you just want to change the edit button, you will probably have to create a new edit `<CustomAction>` that uses javascript, see this example:

http://www.chakkaradeep.com/post/Using-the-SharePoint-2010-Modal-Dialog.aspx

Its for a different button, but you should get the idea.

And then you will need to build a `<HideCustomAction>` to hide the original edit button

Answer (score 1):

Check this : http://www.wawawum.com/blog/post.aspx?id=66a5aed2-f530-4687-bd42-1ef0fb379544

Add a Content Editor WebPart to your EditForm, then put the code found in this blog to maximize the Dialog when opening it.

Works very well for me.

Comment: Please don't post links to your own content without mentioning that, and please also include enough information in an answer to be useful without the link.